# Advanced sed command in pyenv installation instructions

Tags: sed

[Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) repository, has the following sed command for bash:

```
sed -Ei -e '/^([^#]|$)/ {a \
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
a \
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
a \
' -e ':a' -e '$!{n;ba};}' ~/.profile
```

How is this working?

Comment: It would be helpful to know your knowledge of `sed` (usage of *addresses* for line filtering, `a`, `n` and `b` commands) and of extended regular expressions (can you understand `^([^#]|$)`?), so we know how deep to explain.

Comment: @Philippos After crying over the answer I have accepted, thank you for your comment, it helped me clarify that all `a`s, `n`s, `b`s are commands. Indeed, I grasped the idea when I read in the answer that the end is an explicit loop. At least I found out in which part of the documentation, the answers for this command lie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that you show adds two lines of text to your `~/.profile` file.  The lines are

```bsh
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

They are added with the `a` command (the GNU `sed` command uses `a` once for each line, needlessly).  The `a` commands are executed as soon as the regular expression `^([^#]|$)` matches.  The regular expression will match on the first line that does not start with `#` or that is empty.  The lines are appended *after* that triggering line.

The end is an explicit loop that simply allows the rest of the document to stay the same by reading in the next line, printing it, and continuing like that until the end of the file.  This avoids adding the two lines of text after every line that matches the regular expression and that triggers the two `a` commands.

The command is rather awkwardly written as it takes some analysis to figure out what it is supposed to be doing.  The gist of it is that it tries to insert new contents after the first line after any initial block of comments in the `~/.profile` file, as early as possible.  It should possibly use `i` rather than `a` to add the lines after the comments rather than after the first line after the comments.

Personally, I would have just added the lines at the *end* of the script:

```bsh
cat >>"$HOME/.profile" <<'PYENV_SETUP_ENDS'
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
PYENV_SETUP_ENDS
```

(Note that `PATH` does not need to be exported again.)

---

With a recent GNU `awk`, you may replicate the `sed` command using

```bsh
awk -i inplace '
    { print }
    !a && (/^[^#]/ || length == 0) {
        print "export PYENV_ROOT=\"$HOME/.pyenv\""
        print "PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
        a = 1
    }' ~/.profile
```

Swap the two blocks in the `awk` code to get the lines added after an initial comment block instead of after the first line after an initial comment block.

---

The same GNU `sed` command, but cleaned up a bit and using a bit more air for presentation:

```bsh
sed -i -f - ~/.profile <<'END_SED'
/^#/ b

a \
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"\
PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH

:again
$ ! {
    n
    b again
}
END_SED
```

Change the `a` command to `i` to insert directly after the first non-comment line.

Comment: Thank you, your answer delineated the confusion I suffered, in the most clear way. Extremely helpful is the example at the end.